# Aligning ticks with histogram intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf, histogram, ybar

I am trying to get the histogram intervals to show up in the graph and for them to line up with the bars but i'm not sure where i am going wrong.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=1.5cm,anchor=north east,rotate=0,align=center}
]
\draw[gray] (0,2) node {$x_1$} (1,1) node {$x_2$} (2,.5) node {$x_3$} (4,0.7) node {$x_4$};
\pgfplothandlerybarinterval
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{2cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0.5cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{4cm}{0.7cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

and the current output:
[image: i want the actual intervals to show up and be aligned with the bars]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Have you tried removing `anchor=north east` for x-tick labels?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused as to why you're using the more primitive form with `\pgfplothandlerybarinterval`  and so on, instead of e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar interval,
  ymin=0
]

\addplot +[
  nodes near coords,
  point meta=explicit symbolic
]
table [meta=m] {
x y    m
0 2    $x_1$
1 1    $x_2$
2 0.5  $x_3$
4 0.7  $x_4$
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]